# How to avoid switching to new tab in Lightning Experience with classic preview of vf page?

Tags: visualforce

I have used apex:outputpanel to open an external webpage for authentication with callback url. When I click on this link, it redirects to external page in new tab. If we place other vf page instead of that external page it is opening in the same window.

And after authentication vf page opening with classic URL(/apex/page).This also need to avoid.

How to avoid this switching to new tab in Lightning Experience?